# How to make a Movement/Maze Collission function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a simple maze where you can simply move around the map.

I already have a movement function but need a function that's something like an if touching colour #fff000 then bounce back.
I haven't been able to think of a way to do it and would like some help.

Down below you will find my code that I used. The maze is pretty simple, you control a nuclear symbol around but it starts on the maze wall.

I would some help on the css to move it off the wall when it starts.

```js
var objImage;

function init() {
  objImage = document.getElementById("image1");
  objImage.style.position = "relative";
  objImage.style.left = "0px";
  objImage.style.top = "0px";
}

function getKeyAndMove(e) {
  var key_code = e.which || e.keyCode;
  switch (key_code) {
    case 37:
      moveLeft();
      break;
    case 38:
      moveUp();
      break;
    case 39:
      moveRight();
      break;
    case 40:
      moveDown();
      break;
  }
}

function moveLeft() {
  objImage.style.left = parseInt(objImage.style.left) - 17 + "px";
}

function moveUp() {
  objImage.style.top = parseInt(objImage.style.top) - 17 + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  objImage.style.left = parseInt(objImage.style.left) + 17 + "px";
}

function moveDown() {
  objImage.style.top = parseInt(objImage.style.top) + 17 + "px";
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.glitch.global/db8bf4ca-15e3-46f7-82cc-f9266324510d/Maze%20code%20thingy.png?v=1671163203972');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="getKeyAndMove(event)">
  <p></p>
  <img id="image1" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/db8bf4ca-15e3-46f7-82cc-f9266324510d/radioactive%20(1).png?v=1670909277902" lenght="100" width="100" />
</body>
```

Comment: One way might be to draw the maze on a canvas and draw the object, in its current position, on another canvas then using getImageData run through to check whether any of the pixels overlap. Bit time consuming though.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but im not an experienced coder and don't know how to code that. May I please have a few ideas?

Comment: Look up canvas and how to draw an image. Then how to get the imageData and go through it pixel by pixel. Go through your object’s pixels and see if both it and the maze canvas at the same  spot both have nonzero alpha values. If so you have overlap. Give it a go and if still stuck put the code you have into your question with a description of what isn’t working.